# PDO query does not return the object

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to run a query against the database, but the PDO does not result in anything.

this works.

```
$coon = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3308;dbname=developer", "root", "");
$fetch = $coon->query("SELECT * FROM users");
var_dump($fetch->fetch());
```

the above code always return true

```
public static function query($statement, $data = null)
{
    $connection = self::get_connection();

    if(!$data)
        return $connection->query($statement);

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($statement);
    return $stmt->execute($data);
}
```

this way always return `true` and not a PDO query object.

I already tried to use a try/catch block to see if there any errors.. but nothing.

I don't know what it can be, because apparently everything is correct.

Answer (score 1):

[`execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns `true` or `false`.

Your `PDOStatement object` (result object,  PDO query object ) is `$stmt`.